# Как поменять https на http

Tags: android

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etEmail, etPassword;
    TextView signin,q1,q2;
    Button btlog;
    String  Email   ;
    String  Password;
    private Context ctx = this;
    private String token = null;
    private String z = "SecretToken";
    private String x = "NotFound";
    private String c = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uniqname);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uniqpassword);
        btlog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlog);
        signin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup);


        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(login.this,
                        regitractivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        btlog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Email    = etEmail.getText().toString();
                Password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                GetKeyTask getToken = new GetKeyTask();
                getToken.execute();

            }
        });
    }
    private void signin() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        if(token != z)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this,Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }


    class GetKeyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Начинаем асинхрон", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://3sports.ru/signin/");

                HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();


                String urlParameters = "username="+Email+"&password="+Password;

                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                dStream.flush();
                dStream.close();

                int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                String output = "Request URL " + url;
                output += System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Request Parameters " + urlParameters;
                output += System.getProperty("line.separator") + "Response Code " + responseCode;

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder responseOutput = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseOutput.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
                output += System.getProperty("line.separator") + responseOutput.toString();

                token = output;

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject( responseOutput.toString() );
                token = jsonObject.getString("token");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
         //   TextView outputView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postOutput);
            //Toast.makeText(ctx, "Заканчиваем асинхрон", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  outputView.setText( token );
            signin();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Меняете строку `https://3sports.ru/signin/` на `http://3sports.ru/signin/`

Comment: менял https на http но другого сайта и приложение крашится

Comment: `HttpsURLConnection` замените на `HttpURLConnection`. А еще лучше на [okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: HttpsURLConnection замените на HttpURLConnection менял . К попробую okhttp